# Uploading an image using FileUpload tool within Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, image, upload

I am creating a content management system(CMS) and I have been asked to include image uploading, the requirements for the image are below:

```
Check that the image in JPEG or PNG format. 
Check to see that an image with the same filename isn’t already stored on your site.
Check that the image file is under 150K in size and the image is no greater than 400 X 400 pixels (if not the image must be resized to that specification).
The image must be stored in a folder and not in the database itself
The image must referenced in a relevant database table
```

So far i have the following code:

```
   Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Dim filename As String

    Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Property/") + filename)
    Dim width As Integer = img.Size.Width
    Dim height As Integer = img.Size.Height
    If PhotoUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 153600 Then
        If PhotoUploadControl.HasFile Then
            If PhotoUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType = "image/jpeg" Then
                If PhotoUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 153600 Then
                    Try
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(PhotoUploadControl.FileName)
                        PhotoUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Property/") + filename)
                        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!"
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message
                    End Try
                Else
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Please upload an image"
                End If
            Else
                StatusLabel.Text = "Please upload an image less than 150k"
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Has anyone any idea how i would go about this?

Comment: You're almost there, what is your problem?

Comment: I am stuck here - Check that the image file is under 150K in size and the image is no greater than 400 X 400 pixels (if not the image must be resized to that specification). Also how do i change < 102400 to 150k?

Answer (score 1):

The 150K => that means 150 KiloByte. The content-length is set in bytes so that would be (150 * 1024) => 153600

As for the dimensions of the Image you could do this:

```
Dim img as System.Drawing.Image= System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NewAdmin/") + filename)

Dim width as Integer = img.Size.Width
Dim height as Integer = img.Size.Height
```

After that you check its dimensions

Comment: Check it such as - If img > 153600 or < 153600 then
img = 153600 end if?

Comment: Yes, but then you're asking the user to upload an image which is EXACTLY 150K, which seems kind of stupid, so just `PhotoUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 153600` will do the trick

Comment: I understand what you mean in the last comment, thanks. However i am getting errors under Image.FromFile and img.Size. The errors are 'FromFile' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' :/

Comment: You need to use the ImageCñass from another namespace. I'll edit the answer to reflect this

Comment: Having another problem now - I will amend my original code above. Getting the error Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: F:\COM 322 Assignment 4\Images\Property\ It was working previous to this though